# Continuity of convolution and uniform continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, uniform-continuity

**Theorem**: Let $f \in C_c^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g \in L_\text{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then the convolution $$(f*g)(x) = \int_{R^n} f(x-y)g(y)dy$$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $x_n \rightarrow x$ and let K a fixed compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_n - supp(f) \subset K$

In proving the theorem we make the explicit observation that $f$, beeing continuous over a compact set, is uniformly continuous by Heine-Borel theorem. Hence, let $\epsilon_n > 0$ and consider $\delta > 0$ such that $|x_n - x| < \delta$, by uniform continuity:

$$
|f(x_n - y) - f(x - y)| < \epsilon_n \chi_K(y) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

with $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$. Here $\chi_K(y)$ denotes the indicator function over K.
Hence we conclude by observing that, because $g \in \mathbb{L}_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

$$
| (f*g)(x_n) - (f*g)(x) | \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(y)| |f(x_n - y) - f(x - y)| dy \leq \epsilon_n \int_{K} |g(y)| dy \stackrel{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0
$$

That is, the convolution is sequentially continuous hence continuous.

In this argument I don't get the point in using uniform continuity of $f$. Where is the advantage? Why is it so crucial to get the thesis? Why we can't conclude by just using the (sequential) continuity of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform continuity in this case says that given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\textit{for every}$ $x_n-y, x-y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $|(x_n-y)-(x-y)|=|x_n-x| < \delta$, we must have $|f(x_n-y)-f(x-y)|<\epsilon$. Continuity alone makes us fix one of the points (i.e. would make us fix either $x_n-y$ or $x-y$), and then says that there exists a $\delta$ such that for all other points in the domain, we have an analogous implication. But in this context, we are integrating over $y$, so both $x_n-y$ and $x-y$ are changing. So, we need a $\delta$ that will work for all pairs of points at once.

Comment: Exactly as this. I just made a minor edit for clarity.

Comment: So with continuity alone we get the bound only for a specific pair of point. Say $f$ is continuous at $x-y$ then we can say $|f(x_n - y) - f(x - y)| < \epsilon$ only for this specific point $x-y$. If we change $y$ we need to change $\epsilon$ and so we are not able to get a bound which is independent on the choice of points, and hence we are unable to bound the integral (which ranges over $y$). With uniform continuity we are saying: it doesn't matter how we choose the $y$, if the condition $|x_n - x| < \delta$ is verified we will always have the bound $|f(x_n - y) - f(x - y)| < \epsilon$